# SimpleCV PIL Installation HELP NEEDED

Tags: python, installation, simplecv

Trying to install SimpleCV on my Mac (10.9).

Using instructions from:
https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/blob/develop/README.markdown#mac-os-x-106-and-above

Got to the part where it says to install PIL without too many problems:

"Download PIL:

curl -O -L http://effbot.org/media/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz

In the unpacked folder:

python setup.py build --force

sudo python setup.py install"

When I try "python setup.py build --force"

I get a huge mess and a fatal error:
_imagingft.c:73:10: fatal error: 'freetype/fterrors.h' file not found

Tried looking around and haven't found a solution.

What does this mean and what should I do??

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[These](https://github.com/sightmachine/simplecv#mac-os-x-106-and-above) instructions might help you out.

You really don't want to mess with your system Python. Using homebrew, you can can virtualenv and different versions of Python installed.

You'll need to have XCode installed too.